# How to set a texture to one side of a plane and have a color on the other side?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to make a plane in three.js that one side is a texture and the other side is a color. I tried:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.FrontSide, map: texture});
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);
plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

However this makes a plane that only one side has the texture and the other side is completely transparent. If I go:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
```

Then both sides have the color. Is there a way to make it so one side has a texture and the other side has the color?

Comment: Just a related [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/change-the-texture-image-of-one-side-of-a-circlegeometry-object-within-a-time-interval/5525/5?u=prisoner849) about a simple custom `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one patten you can follow if you want a different material on the front and back of a mesh:

```
var group = new THREE.Group();

scene.add( group );

group.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } ) ) );

group.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.BackSide } ) ) );
```

Another approach is to write your own custom `ShaderMaterial`, but the above is the easiest if you are just getting started with three.js

three.js r.104